# How do I layer events with the traffic sources?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a newbie to Google Analytics so please excuse if this is a super simple question. I have a website which has a icon to redirect the user to the App Store page for a mobile app. I have set up event tracking so GA is tracking whenever a user clicks on the link.

How can I set up a report which shows the # of unique visitors that are coming into my page and then how many of these visitors have clicked the download icon?

Basically I'm looking for an customized Traffic sources report like this:

**Source** / **Unique Visitors** / **Unique Visitors Who Initiated Download Event**

google / 100 / 20

direct / 30 / 10

techcrunch / 20 /5

This way I can calculate the download rate of each traffic source.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a custom segment (advanced segments -> new custom segment -> include event action = ) and apply it to the sources -> all traffic report.

Or you go to "Customization -> new custom report", select "flat table", enter "Source/Medium" as dimension, "Unique Visitors" (or page impressions or whatever) as metric and your event action as filter.